# Erro de DLL ao instalar o node.js no Windows 10

Tags: windows, dll, windows-10, node.js

Quando vou instalar o node.js no Windows 10 aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> There is a problem with this windows installer package. A DLL required
>   for this install to complete could to not be run.Contact your support
>   personel or package vendor.

Como posso identificar qual DLL esta faltando?

Comment: Tenta instalar como administrador , acho que deve ser algum problema de privilégio/acesso/segurança

Comment: como instalo como administrador?

Comment: clica com o botão direito no setup.exe e depois na opção "executar como administrador"

Comment: Esta opção não existe.